# Declaration Expected vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to coding and don't really know why I'm being given a message that says **"declaration expected"** on the bottom line with the `greenCount` section of the line with this code. The code pretty much explains what I want but anyway I have three variables, `totalCount`, `redCount` and `greenCount`.

The value of `greenCount` should be `totalCount` subtract `redCount`.
Can anyone help?

```
Public Class Form1

Dim totalCount As Integer = 44
Dim redCount As Integer
Dim greenCount As Integer greenCount = totalCount - redCount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is expecting `greenCount = totalCount - redcount` to be inside a Sub or Function. That is the "declaration" it thinks is missing.

You need something more like this to keep the compiler happy...

```
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim f As New Form1
        Call f.ChangeGreenCount(42)
    End Sub
End Module


Public Class Form1

    Dim totalCount As Integer = 44
    Dim greenCount As Integer

    Public Sub ChangeGreenCount(redCount As Integer)
        greenCount = totalCount - redCount
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible ways to correct this error and you meet the first.

- Move the nondeclarative statement to the body of a procedure.
- Begin the declaration with an appropriate declaration keyword.
- Ensure that a declaration keyword is not misspelled.

Maybe you need a tutorial to learn vb.net while coding, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/visual-basic/).